# Call executable from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have an exe that is currently setup as a Windows Scheduled Task, as follows:

```
Cmd:            C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments:      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:8080/com.voxeo.phytel.dialer/MakeCalls" -Method Get
Start in:       C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\
```

I want to instead invoke it from C# code.
Note that I'm restricted to v1.0 of PowerShell.

Comment: Look at System.Diagnostics.Process (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you asking how to start the Windows Scheduled Task from C#, or are you just asking how to launch powershell.exe (with the given arguments and start directory) from C#?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment, look into [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). They really couldn't make it much easier.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = "Invoke-RestMethod -Uri \"http://localhost:8080/com.voxeo.phytel.dialer/MakeCalls\" -Method Get";
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Just FYI, your question got voted down because you put no effort into finding an answer before posting your question.